# Edit button on post shows no suggested edits

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, user-interface

I have posted a question, someone asks for more information. When I pressed <kbd>Edit</kbd> to provide that information, an empty list showed up and now I have no way of getting my question answered.

Here is [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77507330/how-to-properly-expose-the-bun-inspector-inside-a-docker-container).

**The edit button shows that there is one pending suggestion**

[image: picture of the question]

**When clicked opens an empty list**
[image]

I believe this is a bug unless there is some feature I'm unaware that makes this behavior make sense.

Comment: You don't have enough reputation to handle pending edits, so I guess it should either make the edit link not clickable for you, or display some message here. Hmm, on second thought, given it is your own question, I believe you should be able to accept or reject the edit. In any case, definitely looks like a bug to me.

Comment: It looks like you managed to [approve the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/35285822) somehow?

Comment: It definitely looks like an issue populating that popup suggested edit window. Since the review task has been completed, however, there isn't really any way to reproduce this specific instance any more. Perhaps, it was some transient network issue since you were eventually able to approve the edit.

Comment: @snakecharmerb yes I did, after a minute or so the edits somehow showed up. Maybe it sets the suggestion flag once someone starts creating a suggestion and not when they finish? Either way I got it working